Levi Civita Tensors to scalar terms
In FeynCalc I can do something like this for vectors:
    ScalarProduct[p1, p2] = p1p2;

My problem is that I want to do something similar for term with Levi-Civita tensor:
    LC[a,b,c,d].FV[p1,a].FV[p2,b].FV[p3,c].FV[p4,d]

So basically all I want to do is introduce a placeholder in place of the Levi-Civita terms so that I finish my calculations.
